# How can I remove this drawer?

Tags: drawers

My basement utility sink has a drawer underneath that I want to remove, but I can't figure out how to do it. In hopes of finding instructions, there are no vendor markings on it, and I've compared it to sinks available at places like Home Depot or Lowes without any luck. I've watched various YouTube videos about how to remove various kinds of drawers, but haven't found any quite like this one. Including some photos. In the last photo, I circled a plastic part. In many of the videos I saw suggestions to try moving around plastic tabs in order to remove the drawer, but this one doesn't appear movable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: With the full extension drawer glides that are used to support the basket and the way the basket covers all the possibility of releasing the drawer glides. (The one you have circled is not a release point, so I think) The basket will be required to be removed out of the way first,  since the release points for most full extension glides that I am aware of are on the side that is covered by the white metal base frame of the basket. The pictures given do not show enough detail under the bin or at potential release points to give direction.

Comment: the red circled component is a bumpet

Comment: I would look underneath, or outside the (fully extended) rails for something you can push in order to release the basket.  A photo of the outside of the rail would be helpful.  Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I believe if you pull the drawer out as far as it will go, and look on the side of the rails you will see a little lever [image: See pic]  That leaver must be held down on one side and up on the other (Or vise-versa) and the drawer will be released to be pulled out.  You MUST hold the levers up and down before the drawer is pulled or they may bind.  It helps to have someone help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have access to all mounting screws through the basket.

With a screw driver or long drive bit you could remove the gliders from the cabinet, rather than attempt to separate the gliders or remove the basket from the glider.